# Area as a complex number?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

So I was trying to solve the following integral -

$$\int_{2006}^{2020} \frac{\ln^{i}(\psi^{i})}{\psi} d\psi$$
Wasn't that bad actually (you can find the question and it's solution [here](https://brilliant.org/problems/a-special-integral/?ref_id=1601807)). But I wasn't expecting the answer to be a complex number ($\approx 0.00064 + 0.0013i$). So my question is -

- Can the area under a graph be interpreted as a complex number? If so, how?
- Is this something common for functions that involve complex numbers? (imginary powers for example)
- Finally, is this even an area?

Comment: It's a good question to ponder what complex area means. (Hint: Is this actually area?)

Comment: Are you comfortable with negative area in an integral? It's just as nonsensical geometrically but it's the same idea. When the curve goes into the negative real space, the area is a negative real number. When the curve goes into the imaginary space, the area is an imaginary number. None of it is *really* area, we can only use the area interpretation for the integral of a positive real function.

Comment: The answer is not public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a complex number instead as a real vector of length $2$ dotted with the vector $\langle 1, i \rangle$. For example, $3+5i = \langle 3, 5 \rangle \cdot \langle1, i\rangle$. Then a function $f(x) = f_r(x) + if_i(x)$ is equal to $\langle f_r(x), f_i(x) \rangle \cdot \langle1, i\rangle$.

The integral of $f(x)$ would then be equal to $$\langle1, i\rangle\cdot\int_a^b \langle f_r(x), f_i(x)\rangle dx = \langle1, i\rangle \cdot\left\langle \int_a^bf_r(x)dx, \int_a^bf_i(x)dx\right\rangle$$

This sort of reasoning could also extend to quaternions and other number systems. Each integral is the sum of the individual integrals (or areas) multiplied by the quantity ($1, i$, quaternion units, etc).

Comment: This answer neither gives any understanding of what integration in geometrical or physical terms means, nor is it promoting a mathematical setup used at any place of the world.

Answer (score 4):

While we're integrating over a real variable, the integrand is complex. With the linearity condition $\int_a^b(f+ig)d\psi=\int_a^bfd\psi+i\int_a^bgd\psi$, the problem reduces to calculating the areas under two real-valued functions.

Comment: Let the original integral be $I$. Then, we know that it is just the area underneath a function. But I find these two definitions (area and a complex number) somewhat conflicting with each other. Is there another way to interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the idea that an integral is an "area" is somewhat mistaken.  Finding areas is an application area of integration, but that isn't what an integral actually *is*.  What an integral actually *is* can be thought of as either (a) an infinite sum of infinitely small values, or (b) an antiderivative.

Integrals are *used* for areas.  The area of a rectangle is height times width.  If you take a curve, and want to know the area, we can break it up into equally-wide, infinitely small rectangles.  The height of each rectangle will be $y$ and the width will be $dx$.  So the area of any given rectangle will be $y\,dx$.  Therefore, the sum of them will be $\int y\,dx$.  If $y$ is a function of $x$, we can use the antiderivative to find an equivalent value.

So, as you see, the integral is an *application* of integrals, but not equivalent to areas.  In this case, you do have an infinite sum of infinitely small values, but not something that would really be considered an area under the curve.  It does work as an integral, but not from the "area" understanding of it.